# Set withCredentials attribute for XMLHttpRequest in Socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io

I'm getting the following error using socket.io

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://******:3000/socket.io/?
EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LPBFdGH. A wildcard '*' cannot be used in the 'Access-Cont
rol-Allow-Origin' header when the credentials flag is true. 
Origin 'https://*****.com' is therefore not allowed 
access. The credentials mode of an XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the 
withCredentials attribute
```

I've used CORS to set the attribute to no avail.

app.use(cors({
origin: true,
credentials: true
}));

Are there are any other methods?

Answer (score 2):

```
A wildcard '*' cannot be used in the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header when the credentials flag is true.
```

The key point here is that the `origin:true` part of your CORS configuration produces a `*` value for the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header. This is not acceptable when using the `withCredentials` attribute for the XHR request in socket.io.

You need to explicitly allow the origin, for example like this:

```
app.use(cors({ origin: 'https://******.com', credentials: true }));
```